# how to write vector with different length in a file?

Tags: matlab, vector, printf

I have 7 vectors (L_mean_argil, L_Min_argil,    L_Max_argil,    R_mean_argil,   R_Min_argil,    R_Max_argil, Zero_argil) with different lengths and I want to create a .sae file with all the vectors. Here my code:

```
fileID = fopen('BN_for_prediciting_zeros_argilliti_v1.sae','w');
fprintf(fileID,'L_mean_argil,   L_Min_argil,    L_Max_argil,    R_mean_argil,   R_Min_argil,    R_Max_argil, Zero_argil\n');
fprintf(fileID,'%6.4f, %6.4f, %6.4f, %6.4f, %6.4f, %6.4f, %6.4f \n', L_mean_argil,  L_Min_argil,    L_Max_argil,    R_mean_argil,   R_Min_argil,    R_Max_argil, Zero_argil');
fclose(fileID);
```

It doesn't write vectors properly. Someone can help me?

I expect this:

```
L_mean_argil(1)   L_Min_argil(1)   ...  Zero_argil(1)
L_mean_argil(2)   L_Min_argil(2)   ...  Zero_argil(2)
...
L_mean_argil(end) L_Min_argil(end) ...  Zero_argil(end)
```

But in the final part of some vectors, there will be empty cells associated to others with values

Comment: What do you want to happen with the missing values at the end?  Fill with NaN or just leave blank?  Are your vectors cell array or numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer assuming you want to leave blanks in rows with missing data.

```
%Sample Data all of different lengths
a = 1:4;
b = (1:6)+1;
c = (1:5)+2;

%Get max length
maxSize = max([numel(a) numel(b) numel(c)]);

%Convert to Cell array if it isn't already
a = num2cell(a,1);
b = num2cell(b,1);
c = num2cell(c,1);

%Initialize a cell to hold everything. Init to the max size
output = cell(3,maxSize);
output(1,1:numel(a)) = a;
output(2,1:numel(b)) = b;
output(3,1:numel(c)) = c;

%Print...
fprintf('%0.1f,%0.1f,%0.1f\n',output{:})
```

Results in the this:

```
1.0,2.0,3.0
2.0,3.0,4.0
3.0,4.0,5.0
4.0,5.0,6.0
,6.0,7.0
,7.0,
```